# How to remove Mingw version information from PE?

Tags: compilation, mingw

When using mingw, the compiler adds a lot of version strings in the `.rdata` section. For instance in linux:

```
GCC: (Gentoo Hardened 4.8.1-r1 p1.2, pie-0.5.7) 4.8.1
GCC: (Gentoo Hardened 4.8.1-r1 p1.2, pie-0.5.7) 4.8.1
GCC: (Gentoo Hardened 4.8.1-r1 p1.2, pie-0.5.7) 4.8.1
...
```

Or in windows:

```
GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1
GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1
GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1
...
```

Is there a way to remove them, or at least to put them into a separate section (such as .comment)?

Thanks!

Comment: With `-nostdlib` mingw inserts only one string. But you lose a lot of magic :)

Comment: An with `-Qn` (which is the default for gcc), also the last string is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

propper solution: recompile your toolchain without `--with-pkgversion` flag.

hacky solution: open `g++` in hex editor, find said string, replace with `0x00`s